# How to use find_element_by_link_text() properly to not raise NoSuchElementException?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a HTML code like this:

```
<div class="links nopreview"><span><a class="csiAction"
href="/WebAccess/home.html#URL=centric://REFLECTION/INSTANCE/_CS_Data/null">Home</a></span>&nbsp;•&nbsp;<span><span><a class="csiAction"
href="/WebAccess/home.html#URL=centric://SITEADMIN/_CS_Site">Setup</a></span>&nbsp;•&nbsp;</span><span><a
title="Sign Out" class="csiAction csiActionLink">Sign Out</a></span></div>
```

I would like to click on the link that has the text **Home**. As this Home link appears after login, I have a code like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import re

browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox
browser.get("http://myServer/WebAccess/login.html") # Load App page
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("LoginID") # Find the Login box
elem.send_keys("Administrator")
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("Password") # Find the Password box
elem.send_keys("Administrator" + Keys.RETURN)
#try:
elem = browser.find_element_by_link_text("Home")
elem.click()
```

The part till login works great. However the last but one line is problematic

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_link_text("Home")
```

It raises this NoSuchElementException where the Home link is there as you can see from the HTML code.

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Home"}'
```

Any guidance as to what I am doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you tried adding an implicit wait to this so that it waits instead of running to quickly.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import re

browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox

browser.implicitly_wait(10) #wait 10 seconds when doing a find_element before carrying on

browser.get("http://myServer/WebAccess/login.html") # Load App page
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("LoginID") # Find the Login box
elem.send_keys("Administrator")
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("Password") # Find the Password box
elem.send_keys("Administrator" + Keys.RETURN)
#try:
elem = browser.find_element_by_link_text("Home")
elem.click()
```

The `implicitly_wait` call makes the browser poll until the item is on the page and visible to be interacted with.

Comment: you can also use time.sleep(sleep_time_in_seconds) instead of browser.implicitly_wait(sleep_time_in_seconds).

Comment: No,  time.sleep and browser.implicitely_wait do  quite different things. time.sleep just waits for 10 seconds. implicitely_wait triggers on a find command and then sets a 10 second timeout on it.

Answer (score 5):

The most common issues with [`NoSuchElementException`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException) while the element is there are:

- the element is in different window/frame, so you've to [switch to it first](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#moving-between-windows-and-frames),
- your page is not loaded or your method of [page load is not reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18729483/55075).

Solution could include:

- check if you're using the right frame/window by: `driver.window_handles`,
- write a wait wrapper to wait for an element to appear,
- try XPath instead, like: `driver.find_element_by_xpath(u'//a[text()="Foo"]').click()`,
- use `pdb` to diagnose your problem more efficiently.

See also: [How to find_element_by_link_text while having: NoSuchElement Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18023678/55075)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the element you are looking for doesn't exactly match that text string?
I know it can be tricky if it looks like it does on-screen, but sometimes there are oddities embedded like this simple markup "*H*ome" or "*H*ome" which makes the first char italic:

```
"<i>H</i>ome" is visually identical to "<em>H</em>ome" but does not match text.
```

Edit: after writing the above answer, I studied the question closer and discovered the HTML sample does show "Home" in plain text, but was not visible due to long lines not wrapping.  So I edited the OP to wrap the line for readability.

New observation: I noticed that the Logout element has a "title" attribute, but the Home link element lacks such--try giving it one and using that.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an implicit wait to this in order to wait, instead of running too quickly. 
Or 
else you can `import time` and use `time.sleep(25)`

Comment: Obviously this should be only a last resort.