# Wait until page is loaded with Selenium WebDriver for Python

Tags: python, selenium, execute-script

I want to scrape all the data of a page implemented by a infinite scroll. The following python code works.

```
for i in range(100):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(5)
```

This means every time I scroll down to the bottom, I need to wait 5 seconds, which is generally enough for the page to finish loading the newly generated contents. But, this may not be time efficient. The page may finish loading the new contents within 5 seconds. How can I detect whether the page finished loading the new contents every time I scroll down? If I can detect this, I can scroll down again to see more contents once I know the page finished loading. This is more time efficient.

Comment: It might help to know a little more about the page.  Are the elements sequential or predictable?  You could wait for elements to load by checking visiblity using id or xpath

Comment: I am crawling the following page: http://www.pinterest.com/cremedelacrumb/yum/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reliably detect page load or time out, Selenium 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729483/reliably-detect-page-load-or-time-out-selenium-2)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wait for page load in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868439/wait-for-page-load-in-selenium)

Answer (score 455, accepted):

The `webdriver` will wait for a page to load by default via `.get()` method.

As you may be looking for some specific element as @user227215 said, you should use `WebDriverWait` to wait for an element located in your page:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("url")
delay = 3 # seconds
try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'IdOfMyElement')))
    print "Page is ready!"
except TimeoutException:
    print "Loading took too much time!"
```

I have used it for checking alerts. You can use any other type methods to find the locator.

**EDIT 1:**

I should mention that the `webdriver` will wait for a page to load by default. It does not wait for loading inside frames or for ajax requests. It means when you use `.get('url')`, your browser will wait until the page is completely loaded and then go to the next command in the code. But when you are posting an ajax request, `webdriver` does not wait and it's your responsibility to wait an appropriate amount of time for the page or a part of page to load; so there is a module named `expected_conditions`.

Comment: What is "IdOfMyElement"? Is it something I should predict like the index of something will be loaded newly? For example, I want to crawl the following page: http://www.pinterest.com/cremedelacrumb/yum/

Comment: You should find an element in your page which you're sure that always exists in the page. "IdOfMyElement" refers to an element's ID in the page; if it doesn't own an ID, you can use any other type of locator, like `xpath`.

Comment: I think it should not be something always existing. It should be something that will be newly loaded once scrolling down. Am I right? For example, can you tell me what is this element of the page I said before?

Comment: The link `<a href="/" id="logo" class="logo" data-force-refresh="1" data-element-type="146">Pinterest</a>` is such an element in the link you have provided. BTW, chekout my edit.

Comment: I was getting "find_element() argument after * must be a sequence, not WebElement" changed to "WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "IdOfMyElement"))) " see manual http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html

Comment: The comment by @fragles and the answer by David Cullen were what worked for me.  Perhaps this accepted answer could be updated accordingly?

Comment: Passing `browser.find_element_by_id('IdOfMyElement')` causes a `NoSuchElementException` to be raised. The [documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) says to pass a tuple that looks like this: `(By.ID, 'IdOfMyElement')`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37303115/3657941)

Comment: Hopefully this helps someone else out because it wasn't clear to me initially: WebDriverWait will actually return a web object that you can then perform an action on (e.g. `click()`), read text out of etc. I was under the mistaken impression that it just caused a wait, after which you still had to find the element. If you do a wait, then a find element afterward, selenium will error out because it tries to find the element while the old wait is still processing (hopefully that makes sense). Bottom line is, you don't need to find the element after using WebDriverWait -- it is already an object.

Comment: Does the webdriver wait for the images to be loaded before continuing with the rest of the script?

Comment: @PetarVasilev, if you're referring to `get` method, you can read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664808/difference-between-webdriver-get-and-webdriver-navigate?answertab=active#tab-top).

Comment: @Gopgop _Wow this is so ugly_ is not a constructive comment. What is ugly about it? How could it be made better?

Comment: @ModusTollens The selenium authors need to export simple functions similar to "find_element_by_id" for example, "wait_for_element_by_id". The current way of doing this is off the API structure.

Comment: A more serious problem is when the browser returns stale entries after clicking. Waiting for some time is the only solution. Even then it is not guaranteed to work if the page takes more time to load.

Comment: I use EC.visibility_of_element_located instead of EC.precense_of_element_located because visibility will wait until it is shown from being hidden and presence won't.

Answer (score 121):

Trying to pass `find_element_by_id` to the constructor for `presence_of_element_located` (as shown in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26567563/3657941)) caused `NoSuchElementException` to be raised. I had to use the syntax in [fragles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3111047/fragles)' [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/selenium-python-how-to-wait-until-the-page-is-loaded#comment52897826_26567563):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('url')
timeout = 5
try:
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'element_id'))
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
except TimeoutException:
    print "Timed out waiting for page to load"
```

This matches the [example in the documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits). Here is a link to the [documentation for By](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=#module-selenium.webdriver.common.by).

Comment: Thank you! yes, this was needed for me too.  ID isn't the only attribute that can be used, to get full list, use help(By).  E.g. I used `EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@title='Check All Q1']"))`

Comment: That's the way it works for me as well!
I wrote an additional [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40037216/5802289) expanding on the different locators that are available with the `By` object.

Comment: I've posted a followup question dealing with expectations where different pages may be loaded, and not always the same page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51641546/selenium-presence-of-one-of-many-elements-located

Comment: In some cases this method does not work. For example, if you scrape page one and then get page two of a same website, all Ids in two pages are the same and `.until(element_present)` always will be `True`.

Answer (score 74):

Find below 3 methods:

#### readyState

Checking page readyState (not reliable):

```
def page_has_loaded(self):
    self.log.info("Checking if {} page is loaded.".format(self.driver.current_url))
    page_state = self.driver.execute_script('return document.readyState;')
    return page_state == 'complete'
```

> The `wait_for` helper function is good, but unfortunately `click_through_to_new_page` is open to the race condition where we manage to execute the script in the old page, before the browser has started processing the click, and `page_has_loaded` just returns true straight away.

#### `id`

Comparing new page ids with the old one:

```
def page_has_loaded_id(self):
    self.log.info("Checking if {} page is loaded.".format(self.driver.current_url))
    try:
        new_page = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
        return new_page.id != old_page.id
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
```

> It's possible that comparing ids is not as effective as waiting for stale reference exceptions.

#### `staleness_of`

Using `staleness_of` method:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def wait_for_page_load(self, timeout=10):
    self.log.debug("Waiting for page to load at {}.".format(self.driver.current_url))
    old_page = self.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
    yield
    WebDriverWait(self, timeout).until(staleness_of(old_page))
```

---

For more details, check [Harry's blog](http://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/how-to-get-selenium-to-wait-for-page-load-after-a-click.html).

Comment: Why do you say that `self.driver.execute_script('return document.readyState;')` not reliable? It seems to work perfectly for my use case, which is waiting for a static file to load in a new tab (which is opened via javascript in another tab instead of .get()).

Comment: @ArthurHebert Could be not reliable due to race condition, I've added relevant cite.

Comment: Thank you so much for this response. I had searched so many places to find something that would work while scraping many different websites that all have different elements that load. None of the other results worked.  To get mine working all I did was do a "ready = 'nope',   while ready != 'complete': ready = dv.execute_script(xxxx).  Works great for what I need it to.

Comment: Obey The Testing Goat: - I'm trying to scrape a WordPress wpDataTable front-end to a database on a site that used to just present their data as HTML pages. Now the site presents the data where to get to the second page you need to JavaScript the page. A variation on the "Current Working Solution" got me over my immediate goal line (5 successful scrapes out of 5 tries).

Answer (score 51):

As mentioned in the [answer from David Cullen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37303115/5802289), I've always seen recommendations to use a line like the following one:

```py
element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'element_id'))
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
```

It was difficult for me to find somewhere all the possible locators that can be used with the `By`, so I thought it would be useful to provide the list here.
According to **[Web Scraping with Python](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920034391.do)** by Ryan Mitchell:

> ***`ID`***
>
> Used in the example; finds elements by their HTML id attribute
>
> ***`CLASS_NAME`***
>
> Used to find elements by their HTML class attribute. Why is this
>   function `CLASS_NAME` not simply `CLASS`? Using the form `object.CLASS`
>   would create problems for Selenium's Java library, where `.class` is a
>   reserved method. In order to keep the Selenium syntax consistent
>   between different languages, `CLASS_NAME` was used instead.
>
> ***`CSS_SELECTOR`***
>
> Finds elements by their class, id, or tag name, using the `#idName`,
>   `.className`, `tagName` convention.
>
> ***`LINK_TEXT`***
>
> Finds HTML  tags by the text they contain. For example, a link that
>   says "Next" can be selected using `(By.LINK_TEXT, "Next")`.
>
> ***`PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`***
>
> Similar to `LINK_TEXT`, but matches on a partial string.
>
> ***`NAME`***
>
> Finds HTML tags by their name attribute. This is handy for HTML forms.
>
> ***`TAG_NAME`***
>
> Finds HTML tags by their tag name.
>
> ***`XPATH`***
>
> Uses an XPath expression ... to select matching elements.

Comment: The [documentation for By](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=#module-selenium.webdriver.common.by) lists the attributes which can be used as locators.

Comment: That was what I had been looking for! Thanks!
Well, now it should be easier to find as google was sending me to this question, but not to the official documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the citation from the book. It is much clearer than the documentation.

Answer (score 23):

From [selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py](https://github.com/browserstack/selenium-webdriver-python/blob/master/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py)

```
driver = ...
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    lambda x: x.find_element_by_id("someId"))
```

Answer (score 14):

Have you tried `driver.implicitly_wait`. It is like a setting for the driver, so you only call it once in the session and it basically tells the driver to wait the given amount of time until each command can be executed.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

So if you set a wait time of 10 seconds it will execute the command as soon as possible, waiting 10 seconds before it gives up. I've used this in similar scroll-down scenarios so I don't see why it wouldn't work in your case. Hope this is helpful.

To be able to fix this answer, I have to add new text. Be sure to use a lower case 'w' in `implicitly_wait`.

Comment: What is the difference between implicitly wait and webdriverwait?

Comment: @song0089 Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365040/what-is-the-internal-working-difference-between-implicit-wait-and-explicit-wait/46398760#46398760), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145111/implicit-vs-explicit-vs-fluent-wait/48162909#48162909) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47673679/selenium-implicit-and-explicit-wait-timeout-exception-element-not-found/47676746#47676746) discussions.

Answer (score 9):

Here I did it using a rather simple form:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("url")
searchTxt=''
while not searchTxt:
    try:    
      searchTxt=browser.find_element_by_name('NAME OF ELEMENT')
      searchTxt.send_keys("USERNAME")
    except:continue
```

Answer (score 9):

Solution for ajax pages that continuously load data. The previews methods stated do not work. What we can do instead is grab the page dom and hash it and compare old and new hash values together over a delta time.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

def page_has_loaded(driver, sleep_time = 2):
    '''
    Waits for page to completely load by comparing current page hash values.
    '''

    def get_page_hash(driver):
        '''
        Returns html dom hash
        '''
        # can find element by either 'html' tag or by the html 'root' id
        dom = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html').get_attribute('innerHTML')
        # dom = driver.find_element_by_id('root').get_attribute('innerHTML')
        dom_hash = hash(dom.encode('utf-8'))
        return dom_hash

    page_hash = 'empty'
    page_hash_new = ''
    
    # comparing old and new page DOM hash together to verify the page is fully loaded
    while page_hash != page_hash_new: 
        page_hash = get_page_hash(driver)
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
        page_hash_new = get_page_hash(driver)
        print('<page_has_loaded> - page not loaded')

    print('<page_has_loaded> - page loaded: {}'.format(driver.current_url))
```

Comment: Granted, I haven't experimented with this extensively yet, but this seems to be EXACTLY what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: The best answer, actually. Thank you very much @SoRobby!

Comment: As I know, `find_element_by_tag_name` is not working anymore. `driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'html')` works.

Comment: Hashing whole dom in a while loop? How to say it more precisely... it is not very efficient. :D
One of those solutions, where people fetch million of rows from database in a loop, one by one. :D

Answer (score 6):

How about putting WebDriverWait in While loop and catching the exceptions.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("url")
delay = 3 # seconds
while True:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(browser.find_element_by_id('IdOfMyElement')))
        print "Page is ready!"
        break # it will break from the loop once the specific element will be present. 
    except TimeoutException:
        print "Loading took too much time!-Try again"
```

Comment: you dont need the loop?

Comment: why do you need while True here, as i know until method will wait until deplay timeout

Answer (score 6):

You can do that very simple by this function:

```
def page_is_loading(driver):
    while True:
        x = driver.execute_script("return document.readyState")
        if x == "complete":
            return True
        else:
            yield False
```

and when you want do something after page loading complete,you can use:

```
Driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=Options, executable_path='geckodriver.exe')
Driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

while not page_is_loading(Driver):
    continue

Driver.execute_script("alert('page is loaded')")
```

Comment: that's purey CPU Blocking script.

Comment: Downvoted, it is a really inefficient busy waiting, no one should do that

Comment: Upvoted for correctness. Optimality is a separate issue, but this works in general.

Answer (score 6):

selenium can't detect when the page is fully loaded or not, but javascript can. I suggest you try this.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
```

this will execute javascript code instead of using python, because javascript can detect when page is fully loaded, it will show 'complete'. This code means in 100 seconds, keep tryingn document.readyState until complete shows.

Answer (score 5):

use this in code :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox() # or Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
driver.get("http://www.......")
```

or you can use this code if you are looking for a specific tag  :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox() #or Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.......")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "tag_id"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Very good answers here. Quick example of wait for `XPATH`.

```python
# wait for sizes to load - 2s timeout
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, "//div[@id='stockSizes']//a")))
except TimeoutException:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled a bit to get this working as that didn't worked for me as expected. anyone who is still struggling to get this working, may check this.

I want to wait for an element to be present on the webpage before proceeding with my manipulations.

we can use WebDriverWait(driver, 10, 1).until(), but the catch is **until()** expects a **function** which it can execute for a period of timeout provided(in our case its 10) for every 1 sec. so keeping it like below worked for me.

```
element_found = wait_for_element.until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_class_name("MY_ELEMENT_CLASS_NAME").is_displayed())
```

here is what **until()** do behind the scene

```
def until(self, method, message=''):
        """Calls the method provided with the driver as an argument until the \
        return value is not False."""
        screen = None
        stacktrace = None

        end_time = time.time() + self._timeout
        while True:
            try:
                value = method(self._driver)
                if value:
                    return value
            except self._ignored_exceptions as exc:
                screen = getattr(exc, 'screen', None)
                stacktrace = getattr(exc, 'stacktrace', None)
            time.sleep(self._poll)
            if time.time() > end_time:
                break
        raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to scroll and find all items on a page. You can consider using the following. This is a combination of a few methods mentioned by others here. And it did the job for me:

```
while True:
    try:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        time.sleep(4)
        elem1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element-name")))
        len_elem_1 = len(elem1)
        print(f"A list Length {len_elem_1}")
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        time.sleep(4)
        elem2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element-name")))
        len_elem_2 = len(elem2)
        print(f"B list Length {len_elem_2}")
        if len_elem_1 == len_elem_2:
            print(f"final length = {len_elem_1}")
            break
    except TimeoutException:
            print("Loading took too much time!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nono = driver.current_url
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@value='Send']").click()
  while driver.current_url == nono:
      pass
print("page loaded.")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.