# How to wait a page is loaded in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

```
try:
    next_page_elem = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='%d']" % pageno)

except noSuchElementException:
    break
print('page ', pageno)
next_page_elem.click()
sleep(10)
```

I have a page contains information about reports inside a frame. When i use sleep method to wait for next page to load it works, and without it i kept getting the information on page 1. Beside the sleep is there a better to do this in selenium. I have tried out some previous post that is similar but i think the html i have is quite unique please see example below. [Selenium Python: how to wait until the page is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/selenium-python-how-to-wait-until-the-page-is-loaded) Any help I would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
 <html>
        <div class="z-page-block-right" style="width:60%;">
        <ul class="pageingclass">
        <li/>
        <li>
        <a class="on" href="javascript:void(0)">1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a onclick=" gotoPage('2','2')" href="javascript:void(0)">2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a class=" next " onclick=" gotoPage('2','2')" href="javascript:void(0)"/>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </html>
```

Comment: Does the page URL change when you go from page to page - if yes, can you provide these URLs? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately it does't change.

Comment: what is the variable which changes when you go from page to page? page title or any other element ?

Comment: there is time stamp refreshes with new time stamp<div id="ST_refresh_date" align="right">
Last refreshed:13:33:50 AEDT
<a class="small-block-green-button" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:refreshExportList('Search_Result2');">
<span>
<strong>Refresh</strong>
</span>
</a>
</div>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this element:

```
<a class="on" href="javascript:void(0)">1</a>
```

From what I understand this basically means what page are we currently at.

Since we know the page number beforehand, the idea would be to [wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) until the element with the current page number becomes present:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
try:
    next_page_elem = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='%d']" % pageno)

except noSuchElementException:
    break
print('page ', pageno)
next_page_elem.click()

# wait for the page to load
wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class = 'on' and . = '%d']" % pageno))
)
```

Where `//a[@class = 'on' and . = '%d']` is an XPath expression that would match `a` element(s) with `class="on"` and the text equal to the page number that we paste into the expression via string formatting.

Comment: mate you are a legend. You code has worked. could please explain what is the and is doing inside the class. "//a[@class = 'on' and . = '%d']" Thanks again.

Comment: @RicardLe sure, updated the answer and included some explanation. Also see if the answer can be marked as accepted to resolve the topic. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, i use fireFox FirePath with the following //a[@class = 'on' = 2] and it has selected the right path. thanks