# Waiting for all the resources to load in Selenium with Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am using `Selenium` with `Python` to obtain the `urls` (including `img` urls for ads which are typically located inside nested iframes) of all the resources requested by a webpage. This however, may not work for resources within `iframes` and for `ajax` requests. Reading the documentation on [this](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) and looking at [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/selenium-python-how-to-wait-until-the-page-is-loaded) `StackOverflow` answers, it seems like you can use `ExpectedCondition` to wait for an element to appear. But in my case, where I have to load several websites (several thousand `Top Alexa` sites), there may not be any common element on which I could wait for. I have been using `driver.set_page_load_timeout(60)` for that since `60` seconds seemed like a sufficiently long time for all the nested iframes to eventually turn up. I was wondering if anyone could confirm whether this is the correct way to go about it, and whether there is any other way which is better than this. Thanks.

EDIT: I realize the question has been answered before, but for clarification of the specifics of my question, I believe all those answers offer a solution in terms of detecting an element which you know exists on the page, whereas in my case, I don't have any such knowledge pre-hand.

Comment: have you tried `document.readyState`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use selenium every day, and till my knowledge, there is no way to confirm iframes or ajax loading completely or not, the only thing till now ( in my knowledge) is setting page load time out or time.sleep to the extend that you think it is suitable for the cases that you cant find a common element as an indicator to check if the page load completely or not.
Many questions about this already answered 
[Selenium Python: how to wait until the page is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/selenium-python-how-to-wait-until-the-page-is-loaded)

Comment: Phong Thanks for the answer, I'll try to use the Expected Condition technique. At the moment, the issue I am having is that both `expected_conditions` and `set_page_load_timeout` don't follow the `60s` limit I give them, the first one times out much later, and the second one times out much eariler. Any ideas?