# Selenium xpath behaving differently with python than with ruby

Tags: python, ruby, selenium, xpath

I'm having a strange issue with selenium.

1. This ruby code:

   ```
   page.all(:xpath, "//table[3]//tr[last()]//td")
   ```

   Will get me all the cells of the last row of the third table on a page.
2. This python code:

   ```
   driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[3]//tr[last()]//td")
   ```

   Doesn't return anything at all.

Edit: The issue was with the page loading at different speeds. [Waiting until the page loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/how-to-wait-until-the-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-for-python) solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I was following a page redirect and trying to select elements before they were rendered. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/selenium-python-how-to-wait-until-the-page-is-loaded) answer solved it.