# How to get the state of the cursor?

Tags: python, python-3.8, mouse-cursor

I was wondering if there was any way in Python 3.8 to read the cursor type like how `win32gui` could do with `win32gui.GetCursorInfo()`, Finding the id of the cursor. Below is what I mean by cursor state:

[image: Cursors]

Comment: What's wrong with the way you already know?

Comment: Python 3.8 Doesn't support it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631512/pywin32-and-python-3-8-0

Answer (score 1):

Please find the code below.

reference:
https://www.iditect.com/how-to/10284849.html, but I modified it a little bit:

```
from win32con import IDC_APPSTARTING, IDC_ARROW, IDC_CROSS, IDC_HAND, \
IDC_HELP, IDC_IBEAM, IDC_ICON, IDC_NO, IDC_SIZE, IDC_SIZEALL, \
IDC_SIZENESW, IDC_SIZENS, IDC_SIZENWSE, IDC_SIZEWE, IDC_UPARROW, IDC_WAIT

from win32gui import LoadCursor, GetCursorInfo

def get_current_cursor():
    curr_cursor_handle = GetCursorInfo()[1]
    return Cursor.from_handle(curr_cursor_handle)

class Cursor(object):
    @classmethod
    def from_handle(cls, handle):
        for cursor in DEFAULT_CURSORS:
            if cursor[1].handle == handle:
                return cursor[0] #DEFAULT_CURSORS.index(cursor) , Cursor.__init__
        return cls(handle=handle)

    def __init__(self, cursor_type=None, handle=None):
        if handle is None:
            handle = LoadCursor(0, cursor_type)
        self.type = cursor_type
        self.handle = handle

DEFAULT_CURSORS = (('APPSTARTING',Cursor(IDC_APPSTARTING)), ('ARROW',Cursor(IDC_ARROW)), ('CROSS',Cursor(IDC_CROSS)), ('HAND',Cursor(IDC_HAND)), \
       ('HELP',Cursor(IDC_HELP)), ('IBEAM',Cursor(IDC_IBEAM)), ('ICON',Cursor(IDC_ICON)), ('NO',Cursor(IDC_NO)), ('SIZE',Cursor(IDC_SIZE)),\
       ('SIZEALL', Cursor(IDC_SIZEALL)),('SIZENESW', Cursor(IDC_SIZENESW)), ('SIZENS',Cursor(IDC_SIZENS)), ('SIZENWSE',Cursor(IDC_SIZENWSE)),\
        ('SIZEWE', Cursor(IDC_SIZEWE)), ('UPARROW', Cursor(IDC_UPARROW)), ('WAIT',Cursor(IDC_WAIT)))

while(True):
    print(get_current_cursor())
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made some improvements to be more streamlined

```py
from win32con import IDC_APPSTARTING, IDC_ARROW, IDC_CROSS, IDC_HAND, \
IDC_HELP, IDC_IBEAM, IDC_ICON, IDC_NO, IDC_SIZE, IDC_SIZEALL, \
IDC_SIZENESW, IDC_SIZENS, IDC_SIZENWSE, IDC_SIZEWE, IDC_UPARROW, IDC_WAIT

from win32gui import LoadCursor, GetCursorInfo

DEFAULT_CURSORS = {
    LoadCursor(0, IDC_APPSTARTING): 'appStarting',
    LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW): 'Arrow', LoadCursor(0, IDC_CROSS): 'Cross',
    LoadCursor(0, IDC_HAND): 'Hand', LoadCursor(0, IDC_HELP): 'Help',
    LoadCursor(0, IDC_IBEAM): 'IBeam', LoadCursor(0, IDC_ICON): 'ICon',
    LoadCursor(0, IDC_NO): 'No', LoadCursor(0, IDC_SIZE): 'Size',
    LoadCursor(0, IDC_SIZEALL): 'sizeAll',
    LoadCursor(0, IDC_SIZENESW): 'sizeNesw',
    LoadCursor(0, IDC_SIZENS): 'sizeNs',
    LoadCursor(0, IDC_SIZENWSE): 'sizeNwse',
    LoadCursor(0, IDC_SIZEWE): 'sizeWe',
    LoadCursor(0, IDC_UPARROW): 'upArrow',
    LoadCursor(0, IDC_WAIT): 'Wait',
}


def get_current_cursor():
    curr_cursor_handle = GetCursorInfo()[1]
    res = DEFAULT_CURSORS.get(curr_cursor_handle, 'None')
    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        get_current_cursor()
```