# How to track cursor images in python under Linux

Tags: python, linux, cursor, xlib

What I'd like to do is to track the cursor image that is displayed on the screen, specifically when it changes because I moved in and out of active areas. There are plenty of modules to track the position of the cursor, but the information on the cursor image is rather scare.

I've found one post mentioning that for windows using win32gui:
[The way to detect the current mouse cursor type from bash or python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097307/the-way-to-detect-the-current-mouse-cursor-type-from-bash-or-python)

But is there also a way how to get that under linux using maybe Xlib? I further found that **XFixes** apparently has a method called **XFixesGetCursorImage** and that it's not directly exposed to python, but it was also several years old. Does anybody know whether that has changed or how I could use the C library in python in order to make use of that function (so far no experience on how to do that)?

Comment: XFixesGetCursorImage is from XFixes extension and you need libxfixes in addition to libX11 to use this function. Not sure if puthon bindings you have implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while, but for those interested, I've recently come across this repository that was mentioned in a similar question:

https://github.com/zorvios/PyXCursor/blob/master/pyxcursor/pyxcursor.py

It focuses more on copying the picture of the cursor, but the relevant parts to track the state of the cursor would be:

```
import os
import ctypes
import ctypes.util

PIXEL_DATA_PTR = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong)
Atom = ctypes.c_ulong

class XFixesCursorImage(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('x', ctypes.c_short),
                ('y', ctypes.c_short),
                ('width', ctypes.c_ushort),
                ('height', ctypes.c_ushort),
                ('xhot', ctypes.c_ushort),
                ('yhot', ctypes.c_ushort),
                ('cursor_serial', ctypes.c_ulong),
                ('pixels', PIXEL_DATA_PTR),
                ('atom', Atom),
                ('name', ctypes.c_char_p)]

class Display(ctypes.Structure):
    pass

class Xcursor:
    display = None

    def __init__(self, display=None):
        if not display:
            try:
                display = os.environ["DISPLAY"].encode("utf-8")
            except KeyError:
                raise Exception("$DISPLAY not set.")

        XFixes = ctypes.util.find_library("Xfixes")
        if not XFixes:
            raise Exception("No XFixes library found.")
        self.XFixeslib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(XFixes)

        x11 = ctypes.util.find_library("X11")
        if not x11:
            raise Exception("No X11 library found.")
        self.xlib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(x11)

        XFixesGetCursorImage = self.XFixeslib.XFixesGetCursorImage
        XFixesGetCursorImage.restype = ctypes.POINTER(XFixesCursorImage)
        XFixesGetCursorImage.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(Display)]
        self.XFixesGetCursorImage = XFixesGetCursorImage

        XOpenDisplay = self.xlib.XOpenDisplay
        XOpenDisplay.restype = ctypes.POINTER(Display)
        XOpenDisplay.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]

        if not self.display:
            self.display = self.xlib.XOpenDisplay(display)  # (display) or (None)

    def getCursorImageData(self):
        cursor_data = self.XFixesGetCursorImage(self.display)
        return cursor_data[0]
```

The returned cursor_data[0] contains the information returned by the **XFixesGetCursorImage** function. The relevant information in terms of a change of state is either the **cursor_serial**, which provides some image specific ID or the **name** property which is a string that describes the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can offer you is the code below, from a project of mine `Xwintrack`.
The `Fixes` module under `Xlib` only offers `show_cursor` and `hide_cursor`, that leaves us with just the ability to change existing attributes.

This also means, that because you can't identify the existing cursor or the theme it comes from, you will, if you change the cursor, have to either resort to the standard X cursors or create a cursor of your own, from an image using `PIL` for example. Plus, of course, there's no way back. You'll not be able to revert to the previous cursor, you'll have to provide a guess from the X library.

If you start to dig about, looking into cursors and themes, as implemented, you will discover what a tortuous minefield it is. It appears to be a system of disparate parts, only loosely held together, with cobwebs and spit.

The following relies on:

```
from Xlib import X, display, Xcursorfont
LEFT_PTR = Xcursorfont.left_ptr
SELECT = Xcursorfont.dotbox

def xcursorselect():
    ''' Change the cursor to a green dotbox to indicate a selection is required
        Beware - there is no way back to the original themed cursor - see xcursornormal()
    '''
    disp = display.Display()
    root = disp.screen().root
    font = disp.open_font('cursor')
    cursor = font.create_glyph_cursor(font, SELECT, SELECT+1, (0, 65535, 0), (0, 0, 0)) #green with black edges
    root.change_attributes(cursor=cursor)
    disp.flush()

def xcursornormal():
    ''' Change the cursor back to White left_ptr to indicate selection finished
        Sadly under python there appears to be no way to identify the existing
        cursor image, so we're left with returning to a standard X cursor, rather
        than the Themed one
    '''
    disp = display.Display()
    root = disp.screen().root
    font = disp.open_font('cursor')
    cursor = font.create_glyph_cursor(font, LEFT_PTR, LEFT_PTR+1, (65535, 65535, 65355), (0, 0, 0)) #white with black edges
    root.change_attributes(cursor=cursor)
    disp.flush()
```

If you do come up with a solution, be sure to post it here.