# Detect Mouse Cursor changes in Windows

Tags: python-3.x, pywin32, pyautogui, pynput, pyhook

I will like to know which python library I can use for detecting changes to the mouse pointer state. Say a change from "arrow" to "hand". I have looked at pyhook, pyautogui, pynput, pywin32, pynput. These may have functions for detecting mouse movements and clicks but none dedicated to detecting cursor icon change. I know this can be implemented because i have code implementing it in C++ but just not python. Looking forward to the communities response.

Comment: Looked at *Pynput* twice? :)

Comment: I have just taken a second broader look and still can find nothing on listening for cursor changes. If there is any where i am supposed to look into in particular please let me know @CristiFati

Comment: Did you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57245713/2280890) it indicates that `win32gui.GetCursorInfo()` will include the cursor type via `flags` in the cursor info response.