# Selenium Python: Check that JS variable is true

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to use the selenium package in  python to load up dynamical websites to be saved. But I am having mixed success. I noticed that there is a difference between the pages successfully saved and those not. In the HTML source of the successful ones, I see

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var PageIsReady = true;
</script>
```

whereas for the others, the var PageIsReady is false. Is there a way I can trigger off the saving after the variable has turned true?

This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/how-to-wait-until-the-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-for-python) shows how to do the timing out but it looks for the presence of a tag while I want it triggered off the value of a script variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to handle value of `PageIsReady`, just wait until `<script>` with exact text content appears in DOM:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//script[normalize-space()="var PageIsReady = true;"]')))
```

Answer (score 5):

A nice solution to this problem could be to implement a custom *wait condition* which will check if a variable will get defined or not. The condition would have to look something like this (beware, not thoroughly tested):

```
class js_variable_evals_to_true(object):
    def __init__(self, variable):
        self.variable = variable
    def __call__(self, driver):
        return driver.execute_script("return {0};".format(self.variable))
```

Usage:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

chrome = webdriver.Chrome()
chrome.get("http://google.com")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(chrome, 10).until(js_variable_evals_to_true("toolbar.visible")
finally:
    chrome.quit()
```

Check the [source code](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.html) in the Selenium documentation to learn how to implement custom wait conditions.