# Wait for selenium to load after clicking a button

Tags: python, selenium

I'm experimenting with selenium on python 3.6 a bit and I'm trying to figure out how to wait for the page to load if I'm not using get()

```
    search_button = driver.find_element_by_id("search-icon-legacy")
    search_button.click()
    videos = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("ytd-video-renderer")
```

I'm trying to search in Youtube and get all the videos of the search but sometimes videos is empty and sometimes it isn't

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/how-to-wait-until-the-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-for-python

Answer (score 0):

Speaking straight, you don't have to explicitly wait for **`Page Load`**. Once the **`Page Loading`** gets completed, the client i.e. **`Web Browser`** will send **`document.readyState == "complete"`** to **`Selenium`** and only then **`Selenium`** proceeds to execute the next line of code.

Comment: As I said I'm not Using get()

Comment: @DebanjanB I guess... with get() guy is going to navigate to login page first. So that is fine where get() will return once page is loaded. But on login page, when we hit login button, it is a click operation which will return immediately and we have to wait explicitly for page to be loaded

Comment: @Dcode You are right, I missed to read the `click()` event initially.