# Selenium implicit and explicit wait, timeout exception element not found

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, timeoutexception, implicitwait

I am new to selenium (but experienced java developer).

I am using something like below:

```
WebElement searchBasket = pDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Search&Baskets')]"));
WebElement searchproduct = pDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Search a product')]"));

//if search an agreement is not show up, then click on other menu, then click it back
pWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Search&Baskets')]")));
pDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Search&Baskets')]")).click();

// click on search an agreement
try {
    pWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Search&Baskets')]")));
    action = new Actions(pDriver);
    action.moveToElement(searchBasket).build().perform();

    pWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Search a product')]")));
    searchproduct.click();
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
}
```

where pWait is:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
```

however when I run the test case I get below error:

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(.,'Search&Baskets')]"}
Command duration or timeout: 4 milliseconds
```

I thought it should have wait atleast 15 seconds before throwing this exception. From the log above it looks like it threw exception only in 4ms. 
and i could see on console that as soon as it hit that line, it threw exception.

I have implicit waiting set as 0 and using explicit wait.

Am i missing anything here.

Also, in explicit and implicit wait, is it upto that much time OR exact that much time, 
example if I set implicit wait as 10 sec, then does it mean wait for exact 10 sec OR wait upto 10 sec (if element found then proceed, even if element founf on 6th second)

is above same for explicit wait as well?

Please help

Comment: Hi, I tried doing the same with implicit wait as 0 and with the explicit wait time as 10. It got timed out exactly on the 10th second. Also, it is not suggestible to mix both implicit wait and explicit wait. But it shouldn't be an issue since your implicit timeout is 0 seconds. In case if element is found in the 6th second, then it will proceed to the next step. It won't wait for the entire 10 seconds for both implicit and explicit waits. Can you paste the entire code here?

Comment: Thank ... updated the code...

Answer (score 2):

Let us analyze what is happening in our code.

We have defined two `WebElements` **searchBasket** and **searchproduct** as follows :

```
WebElement searchBasket = pDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Search&Baskets')]"));
WebElement searchproduct = pDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Search a product')]"));
```

We havn't tried to use those WebElements in our code at immediate basis, so had **No Impact**.

Next, we tried *WebDriverWait* for an `WebElement` as follows :

```
pWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Search&Baskets')]")));
```

Again we didn't capture the `return type` of the result, so had **No Impact**.

Now, within the `try{}` block we have again tried *WebDriverWait*:

```
pWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Search&Baskets')]")));
```

But again we havn't captured/acted on the `return type` of the result. That's why moving ahead when we did :

```
action.moveToElement(searchBasket).build().perform();
```

**searchBasket** referred to the `WebElement` which we have stored earlier as :

```
WebElement searchBasket = pDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Search&Baskets')]"));
```

As this first search result (which was without *WebDriverWait*) may not have returned any `WebElement` at all and have returned **Null**.

Finally, the most important factor for the error *Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(.,'Search&Baskets')]"}* is, the 
*WebDriverWait* instance was `wait`. Instead of using `wait` we have always tried to use `pWait`

So for all these reasons, *WebDriverWait* was never implemented properly in our code.

---

### Mixing up *ImplicitWait* & *ExplicitWait*

The [Selenium Documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) clearly mentions the following :

> **WARNING**: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times. For example setting an implicit wait of 10 seconds and an explicit wait of 15 seconds, could cause a timeout to occur after 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

`ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable` invokes `isDisplayed()` and `isEnabled()` methods on EXISTING `WebElement`.

You are providing `By` as a parameter which means, the driver has to find your element first. It failed to do this.

Make sure your element is present by using `wait` until `presenceOfElementLocatedBy(By by)`.

Example:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocatedBy(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Search&Baskets')]")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Search&Baskets')]")));
```