# What is the default wait time of the selenium webdriver before throwing NoSuchElementException

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, nosuchelementexception, fluentwait, implicitwait

There are 3 types of waits in sellenium i.e Implicit Wait,Explicit Wait and Fluent wait. If i don't use any of the waits,How much time does the selenium waits by default before throwing `NoSuchElementException`.

Is it the Implicit Wait used internally by the selenium.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you are right. [Implicit Wait](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits) is implemented internally by the selenium.

- You can find a detailed discussion in [Using implicit wait in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672693/using-implicit-wait-in-selenium/45674706#45674706)

The three(3) different types of waits i.e. [Implicit Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989984/selenium-implicitly-wait-doesnt-work/48991017#48991017), [Explicit Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712431/replace-implicit-wait-with-explicit-wait-selenium-webdriver-java/45715759#45715759) and [Fluent Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275658/the-type-fluentwait-is-not-generic-it-cannot-be-parameterized-with-arguments-w/49690732#49690732) are implemented as per the *usecase* requirements.

- Here you can find a detailed discussion on [What is the internal working difference between Implicit Wait and Explicit Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365040/what-is-the-internal-working-difference-between-implicit-wait-and-explicit-wait/46398760#46398760)

If you don't use any of the waits, as [findElement()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) or [findElements](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-)method is affected by the 'implicit wait' times in force at the time of execution there will be **no** *waiting period*. When implicitly waiting, this method will return as soon as there are more than 0 items in the found collection, or will return an empty list if the timeout is reached.

- Here you can find a detailed discussion on [selenium implicit and explicit wait, timeout exception element not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47673679/selenium-implicit-and-explicit-wait-timeout-exception-element-not-found/47676746#47676746)