# Selenium is slow while finding non-existent through classname using Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Some sites has age limitation, which will ask you whether you are over eighteen years old and you click yes to enter the site or no no to close the page

Here are snippet of code

```
driver.get(url2)
if (len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('certification_layout_01'))==1):
   ask_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('dd.yes a')
   ask_button.click()
```

if selenium find the class `certification_layout_01` then find go further to find anchor link and click to enter the site.

I found that if driver cannot find that class name the page just hold for a period before proceed the remaining statements after the if statement. I felt that it was waiting for a timeout before proceed.

Comment: When you run `driver.get(url)`, selenium will wait until your page has been loaded (equivalent to javascript's `document.readyState === "complete"`). Then it will execute your remain script as you mentioned.

Comment: Are you using an implicit wait? If so, that's probably it.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple aspects behind [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) being slow to find a non-existing element (class) as follows:

- I would suspect you have set the [ImplicitWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672693/using-implicit-wait-in-selenium/45674706#45674706) which gets **baked in** to the *WebDriver* instance.
- You may opt either of the following:

  - [Replace implicit wait with explicit wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712431/replace-implicit-wait-with-explicit-wait-selenium-webdriver-java/45715759#45715759)
  - [How to combine implicit and explicit timeouts in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52706693/how-to-combine-implicit-and-explicit-timeouts-in-selenium/52707885#52707885)
- You may like to look out for the <kbd>Yes</kbd> directly to invoke `click()` and refactor your code as follows:

  ```
  driver.get(url2)
  try:
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "dd.yes a"))).click()
      print("Clicked on Yes button")
  except TimeoutException:
      print("Yes button wasn't found")
      break
  ```

---

### tl; dr

[What is the default wait time of the selenium webdriver before throwing NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55861873/what-is-the-default-wait-time-of-the-selenium-webdriver-before-throwing-nosuchel/55863144#55863144)