# Script freezing when using wait in a for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having a `python` `selenium` script where I am trying to send messages to different users in `Telegram`.

To open any user's page we just need the user's username and we can load its chat page.

```
web = webdriver.Chrome()
web.get(TELEGRAM_WEB_HOMEPAGE)
nameList = get_active_name_list()
for name in nameList:
    web.get(USER_URL + name)
    web.implicitly_wait(2) #HERE IS THE WAIT
    elem = web.find_element_by_class_name('composer_rich_textarea')
    elem.click()
    elem.send_keys(MESSAGE)
    elem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    new_nameList.remove(name)
```

I also tried with `time.sleep(2)`, in all cases the program freezes once it reaches the wait command. And I need to wait for the `url` of next `user` to load.

I also tried using `WebDriverWait` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26567563/6366458).

So, how to solve the problem?

Comment: Are there any errors in selenium console?

Comment: @MarioNikolaus ITs just there freezed and after some time, timeout.

Comment: does it ever loads the page in the loop?

Comment: Can you sum up your exact _Manual Steps_ along with the relevant _HTML_?

Comment: @MarioNikolaus No