# (Python, selenium) implicit and explicit wait not working

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, wait

I am trying to write a webscraping program that:

1) types a name in a search bar

2) presses enter

3) finds the first search result, which is a link to another page

4) clicks the first result

5) finds a specified element on the resultant page

6) copies that element

7) prints that element in PyCharm

8) Repeats for each entry in a preloaded array (set to "names")

Below is the part of the code designed to do this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import xlrd


driver = webdriver.Chrome("path")

i=0
while i < len(names):

    a = names[i]
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(25)
    driver.get("https://www.healthgrades.com/")

    driver.find_element_by_id("search-term-selector-child").send_keys(a)
    driver.find_element_by_id("search-term-selector- 
    child").send_keys(u'\ue007')

    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    first = driver.find_element_by_class_name('uCard__name')
    first.click()

    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    elem= driver.find_element_by_class_name("office-street1")

    entry1 = elem.text
    time.sleep(1)
    print(entry1)
i += 1
```

When I run the program, it looks like the code finishes step 4 (line 13) before the element in that step becomes a link; the error I receive most commonly is

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"office-street1"}
```

I think that means it gets through find_element_by_class_name and executes the click. But when I watch the automated webpage, I notice that the next page never opens.

To fix this, I've tried to put an implicit wait (line 15) before searching for the uCard element, but I still get the same error.

Other attempted solutions:

- Using an explicit wait to wait for the uCard_name element
- Clearing the cache/deleting search history with each loop
- Using [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/how-to-wait-until-the-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-for-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) to stall program

Additional Info:

- Working in Pycharm, Python version 3.6
- Windows 10, 64-bit

Comment: once the driver stop the class is present in the DOM?

Answer (score 3):

The best practice is to use an explicit wait for the element of interest. That way you know it is there before clicking on it or otherwise interacting with it.

So be sure to add these imports:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome("path")

# Only need to do this once per session
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

i=0
while i < len(names):

    a = names[i]
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(25)
    driver.get("https://www.healthgrades.com/")

    driver.find_element_by_id("search-term-selector-child").send_keys(a)
    driver.find_element_by_id("search-term-selector-child").send_keys(u'\ue007') 

    first = driver.find_element_by_class_name('uCard__name')
    first.click()

    timeout = 20
    # Explicitly wait 20 seconds for the element to exist.
    # Good place to put a try/except block in case of timeout.
    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(
           EC.presence_of_element_located(('className', 'office-street1'))
           )
    entry1 = elem.innerText
    ...
```

Comment: `The best practice is to use an explicit wait for the element of interest. `  I really would like to know where you find those best practices.

Comment: What's the point of using the same time for implicit and explicit waits?