# selenium python wait doesn't work

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I tried this

```
WebDriverWait(web.driver,1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
```

and it did nothing literally nothing.

The web is also changing dynamically new elements are introduced to it and the code doesn't exist in the page_source of the new elements.

please help I have been stuck on this all morning

I'm using geckodriver for firefox
python 3

test code

```
_browser_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
_browser_profile.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)
driver=webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile= _browser_profile)
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
wait= WebDriverWait(driver,10)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
```

Comment: Would be nice if you provide a link to the page, or relevant html and also error you get and the code snippet you have so far

Comment: The problem is that i'm not getting any errors

Comment: min i will provide the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wait until the page is loaded with Selenium for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/how-to-wait-until-the-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-for-python)

Comment: a function is not working as it should be in selenium. that's my question why does this code doesn't work. sadly any wait function doesn't work with me even the code in ur referred site

Answer (score 2):

This is just declaration of **explicit wait**.

This will do nothing `WebDriverWait(web.driver,1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)`  , if you do not bind it with EC which is **expected conditions**.

Something like this you have to do :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'someid')))
```

More about Explicit wait can be found at [Selenium python wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

**UPDATE :**

The code you have shared , you are just letting your script know that it has explicit wait.

You are not using explicit wait at all.

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
search_bar = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'q')))
search_bar.sendkeys("Hi Google")
```

Note that, you have to import this :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

I do not know why @Andrei has provided you the worst kind of explicit wait which is nothing but `time.sleep(10)` which should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: sadly it's like there is no waiting is waiting there

Comment: Sorry , I did not get you. Where no waiting is written ?

Comment: it's as if i did not write wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) , i dont know but i think it's a problem with the software not the code

Comment: I originally used that code before the wait but it doesnt work so i tried to look where the problem is and found out that wait doesn't work.. well at this point im really desperate for a solution anything that makes this thing work :\ .

Comment: scroll down wait untill an element show up and then extract it use some regular expression and print it in text.. I did everything .the weird thing is when i scroll down and ask for page_source i only get the old html.I also tried to find the element by command without the source but the driver is still clueless.

Comment: is it possible that the webdriver is not compatibale with my firefox version ? how can i check that ?

Comment: geckodriver-v0.21.0 .. firefox v61, i think it's compatibale

Comment: Yes it is not an issue with drivers though. Once you have scroll down , try to do refresh and then try to get the page_source

Comment: the driver would get the HTML code of the url which is not exactly why i'm running a webdriver instead of requests unless that's not what you meant right?

Comment: I am not able to get you properly.

Comment: the url doesnt change when i scroll down. if i reload it everything i wanted to catch is gone

Comment: Then in that case , you will have to wait till the DOM updates , try to wait till the time when last element get visibility.

Comment: wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((Your locator , 'locator value')))