# WebDriverWait on javascript value

Tags: python, selenium

How would I accomplish the following in python's selenium:

```
el = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
        expected_conditions.js_return_value(
          ("return document.readyState === 'complete' ? true : false")
        )
     )
```

I've seen ways to do the above in Java, but cannot find a similar solution in python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wait until the page is loaded with Selenium for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/how-to-wait-until-the-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-for-python)

Comment: Specifically see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30385843/2386774

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar but used the `__call__` class function to get the same effect, like this:

```
class DynamicLoadState:
    def __call__(self, driver):
        LoadComplete = False
        if driver.execute_script("return document.readyState") == 'complete': LoadComplete = True
        return LoadComplete

WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(DynamicLoadState())
```

Comment: This is more complicated than it needs to be... all you need is `return driver.execute_script("return document.readyState") == 'complete'`. You can remove the lines before and after your `if` statement. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/how-to-wait-until-the-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-for-python/30385843#30385843