# How to replace non standard tag's attribute in python3?

Tags: css, regex, python-3.x, selenium

I have some tags as below, they used non standard tag  with style "display: none". these can't be parsed so that I want to replace `style="display: none;"` to empty string or to `style="display: inline;"`.

```
...
<section id="box3" class="nodisp_zero" style="display: none;">
    <h1 id="box_ttl3" style="display: none;"></h1>
    <img style="width: 100%; display: none;" id="box_img3" alt="box3" src="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/dummy.png" class="lazy" data-original="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808220015_box_img3_A.jpg?1533975785">
    <figcaption id="box_caption3" style="display: none;"></figcaption>
    <div class="textarea clearfix">
        <h2 id="box_subttl3" style="display: none;"></h2>
        <div class="fontL" id="box_com3" style="display: none;"></div>
    </div>
</section>
...
```

I tried to use this code, but I got error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`, what can I do?

```
driver.get(href)
soup_level2 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
soup_level2 = soup_level2.replace(r'display:\s*none', "")
images = soup_level2.find_all('img')
```

Comment: Try `r'display:\s*none'` for parameter 1. What is _parameter 1_ according to docs?

Comment: I just modified my question, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the style attribute like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
for tag in soup.findAll(lambda tag:tag.has_attr('style')):
  tag["style"] = tag["style"].replace("display: none;", "")
```

[**Demo**](https://ideone.com/vF9cLR)

Or using a simple regex replace:

```
html_doc = re.sub(r"display:\s*none;?", "", html_doc, 0)
```

**[Demo](https://ideone.com/EjsXOa)**

---

There are several ways to [wait for the content to be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/how-to-wait-until-the-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-for-python) using Selenium, e.g.

```
element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'element_id'))
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
```

Comment: Your code also doesn't work and I found reason. If I use selenium to get page, the javascript function will be run when page load so that those tags with `<section id="box3" class="nodisp_zero" style="display: none;"><h1 id="box_ttl3" style="display: none;">` not in page_source. if I use only bs4 without selenium, I got all of images.

Comment: @mikezang try to wait for the content. Even sleep the thread for a few seconds could help.

Comment: it is not contents full unloaded problems.