# Why selenium is unable to locate the Disqus comment section?

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, disqus, webdriverwait

**Hello**

I created few selenium scripts before on python and they are working fine but don't know why it's not working on a website.
I'm trying to click on a element which appear when "DISQUS" is loaded on that website.
**Disqus** is a comment section on website which loads after website loading.

So I used sleep method but it didn't work so I tried it with python IDLE to execute code line one by one so I can run locate code once **Disqus comment section** is completely available but still getting same error. "Webdriver unable to locate element"

Here is my code.

```html
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
browser = webdriver.Chrome('E:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('https://www.eloanus.com/customers-review') 
dicuss = browser.find_element_by_class_name('textarea')
print(dicuss)
```

Error, I'm getting.

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer-573G\PycharmProjects\Appium\venv\import selenium.py", line 12, in <module>
    dicuss = browser.find_element_by_class_name('textarea')
  File "C:\python3.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 563, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\python3.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 966, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\python3.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\python3.5\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"textarea"}
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

I attached the screen shot of inspect element (class) from that website.

[Inspect element screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5DJG.png)

I'm new to programming, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `click on a element` click on which element?

Comment: the element is in nested iframe , switch to the frame,  before interaction

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26567563/5699807

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait until page is loaded with Selenium WebDriver for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/wait-until-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-webdriver-for-python)

Comment: Thank you for your help @Newcontributor and cruisepandey both answers are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* to the **Disqus comment section** you need to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired parent *frame to be available and switch to it*
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired nested *frame to be available and switch to it*
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:
- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  browser=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  browser.get('https://www.eloanus.com/customers-review') 
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='disq2disqusCommentsHolder']")))
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@id,'dsq-app') and @title='Disqus']")))
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='textarea'][contains(@aria-label,'Join the discussion')]"))).send_keys("Michael Berger")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Disqus_comment_section]

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple **iframes**, so you have to switch to it before you want the interaction.

It's always a good practice if you switch the control of driver to default once you are done.

**Code :**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'D:/Automation/chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.eloanus.com/customers-review")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

visibilty_login = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Log In']")))

action = ActionChains(driver)

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[id$='disqusCommentsHolder']")))

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[title='Disqus']")))

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 100)") 

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Join the discussion…']/following-sibling::div[@class='textarea']"))).send_keys("Hi")

driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Hope this helps.