# using Python's webdriver to click an element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.policybazaar.com/")
btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="circleTab v3health"]')
btn.click
```

I want to click the "Health" button under the above mentioned website, but it gives me an error:

```
bound method WebElement.click of 
selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement(session="b30bbdb3 
4401-40ab-9827-6fd0d554de50", element="c744a45a-e7ee-419c-9a46- 
bf522ed4f2e2"
```

When I inspect element, I found this:
[Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiINA.png)

What should be correct approach to make the script click health button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Button click is a function, call it with brackets

```
btn.click()
```

You may also like to wait for the page to load see [Wait until page is loaded with Selenium WebDriver for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/wait-until-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-webdriver-for-python) or

```
import time
....
time.sleep (10) # before you call the click function
```