# Selenium - Python - find_element_by_link_text not sure what's wrong

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

This is my first time with both Python and Selenium, and I'm trying to select and click on an element of the navigation bar of this website - stockfetcher.com

I would like to click on the MyFilters tab on the navigation bar. After inspecting the element, I see that the HTML code for that element is

`<a href="/myfilters">
  "MyFilters "
  <span class="tab-pill"></span>
</a>`

And here's what I trying to do

`driver.find_element_by_link_text("MyFilters ").click()`

And I get this error

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'`

Any idea what's wrong? Most examples I watched online did not have "" around whatever is inside the  tag. Is that what's messing me up?

Comment: That error means that you can't call `.click()`, you would get the same error if you replaced `.click()` with `.fsghudghur()`. Whatever `find_element_by_link_text` returns had no `click()` function.

Comment: Try running `type(driver.find_element_by_link_text("MyFilters "))`. See if what is returned is what you want. Also try printing it with `print(driver.find_element_by_link_text("MyFilters "))`. Is that good as well?

Comment: @EthanK I added those in my code, but I didn't see anything on the console. So the method of link_text won't work here?

Comment: Well, if you didn't see anything then it didn't run or you are not looking at the console. And if you got that error, `.click()` won't just not work here, but `.click()` won't work **anywhere**. Check the documentation to make sure `.click()` exists, if not then make sure you are using the right version.

Comment: @EthanK .click() is definitely working. Because preceding this I had to click buttons to log in. Actually I see this in the console=>> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"MyFilters "}

Comment: So whatever `type(driver.find_element_by_link_text("MyFilters "))` is will be different then the `type()` of whatever `.click()` worked for. But for all objects like this one, `.click()` will never work.

Comment: @EthanK Do you by any chance know why it's not working for that one? Or how else can I click on the button?

Comment: Not really, I don't know anything about [tag:selenium], only how python works with functions like `.click()`. I do know that the type of object in this case **is different** then the objects that this *did* work for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link text is sometimes very picky about what you send to it, and I have found that you have to match what the actual link is showing, and not the value following href. Since the site shows `MyFilters`, try doing this instead:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('MyFilters').click()
```

Without the space after ***Filters***. I tested on my side and it seems to work.

Also, the error does not match what you have given as an example, it would throw `NoSuchElementException`, before it would throw that `NoneType` has no *click()* event. Either way the above should work for you.

Comment: Okay, so this works! But it will not work if I place it right after my 'sign in' click. However, if I sandwich another find_element command between them then the second one will work. Could it be that it is trying to click while the page is loading?

Comment: It probably is, I would use things like `WebDriverWait` conditions, to make sure your element is visible first. [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/wait-until-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-webdriver-for-python) post would be helpful with that issue, but it sounds like the click is fixed! So that's good.