# Selenium find_element_by_xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to buy a product, so it needs to be added to the cart which is working but when I am trying to click on the checkout button I get an error.

## open chromedriver

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\x\OneDrive\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')


driver.get('https://feature.com/products/billionaire-boys-club-kids-bb-copilot-polo-black')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-value="3T"]').click()


driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="AddToCart default-btn"]').click()
```

Until this part it is working, but trying to check out it isn't working.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@name="checkout"]').click()

<button type="submit" class="btn--secondary btn--full cart__checkout" 
name="checkout" value="Check Out →">
      Check Out
        </button>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\x\OneDrive\Desktop\Sp\Snx.py", line 35, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@name="checkout"]').click()
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@name="checkout"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you need wait to "checkout" button appears before selenium search and click it

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\x\OneDrive\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://feature.com/products/billionaire-boys-club-kids-bb-copilot-polo-black')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-value="3T"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="AddToCart default-btn"]').click()
time.sleep(2)
cart_container = driver.find_element_by_id('CartContainer')
cart_container.find_element_by_name('checkout').click()
```

This example I used `time.sleep(secs)`, where there's no guarantee that the element was already show up.

If you want improve, there's a class called `WebDriverWait`, more information here: [Wait until page is loaded with Selenium WebDriver for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/wait-until-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-webdriver-for-python)