# Python Selenium can't focus/click element

Tags: python, selenium

just started with both python and selenium and i'm trying to make a script that logs into facebook, then searches for certain person and sends some message, but i have no idea how do i focus facebook's message div. tried both

`browser.execute_script("document.querySelector('._1mf').click();")`

and

`searchBar = browser.find_element_by_class_name('_4po3')`

but it seems like the right element loads after you click on the messagebox so i tried multiple different classnames and still i'm stucked :/

EDIT: just to be clear
i managed to grab specific person from the chat bar by

`searchBarAfterUpdate = browser.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//div[@class = '_364g' and text() = 'personname']")
searchBarAfterUpdate.click()`

and now when i have the chat box open i want to somehow write and send a message

Comment: You can wait until everything loads. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/wait-until-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-webdriver-for-python. Always check for existing answers first.

Comment: it loads after you click or focus message box , if you don't it wont load. I always check for existing answers first, that's why it's my first post after ~half year of learning

Comment: turned out that after message box popped up you can "switch_to_active_element" and then send_keys :P

Comment: OK. I see. That wasn't clear to me.

Comment: Facebook is notoriously difficult to automate from a UI perspective. If you continue running into issues down the line, this may have something to with facebook itself and not selenium.

Comment: Those classes are dynamic. You would need to use text on the page instead.

Comment: that's what i thought, thank you for your answers :)