# Selenium not finding elements Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote a code in selenium to extract number of Rounds in a soccer league, all elements are the same for all pages from what I can see but for some reason, the code works for some links and does not work for others.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from time import sleep

def pack_links(l):

    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(l)

    rnds = driver.find_element_by_id('showRound')
    a_ = rnds.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td[@class='lsm2']")
    #a_ = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('lsm2')

    knt = 0
    for _ in a_:
        knt = knt+1

    print(knt)

    sleep(2)
    driver.close()
    return None

link = 'http://info.nowgoal.com/en/League/34.html'
pack_links(link)
```

Here is a link that works [Nowgoal Serie B](http://info.nowgoal.com/en/SubLeague/40.html), it returns the number of `td` tags with class `lsm2`

and a picture of what the source page looks like [image]

And this one return's 0,for some reason it does not find the tags with class `lsm2` [Nowgoal Serie A](http://info.nowgoal.com/en/League/34.html), and also a picture of the segment of interest
[image]
Even when I trying to find it directly with this commented line `a_ = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('lsm2')` it still returns 0. I will appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, the inner HTML of *td* with "showRound" id is dynamic and loaded by *showRound()* JS function, which in its turn is invoked by script within the page's *head* tag on page load. Consequently, in your case it just seems not to get enough time to load. I've tried to solve this issue in two ways:

1. A kludge one: use *driver.implicitly_wait(number_of_seconds_to_wait)*. I would also recommend to use it instead of *sleep()* in the future. However, this solution is quite clumsy and kind of asynchronous; in other words, it waits primarily for seconds countdown not for result.
2. We may wait for the first element with "lsm2" class to load; if it fails to do so after some reasonable timeout we may stop waiting and raise en exception (thanks to **Zeinab Abbasimazar** for the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/wait-until-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-webdriver-for-python)). This may be achieved through *expected_conditions* and *WebDriverWait*:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

def pack_links(l):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()  # I would also suggest to use this instead of Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")  # To be on the safe side, although it seems to be enabled by default
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("path_to_chromedriver_binary", options=options)
    driver.get(l)
    rnds = driver.find_element_by_id('showRound')

    """Until now, your code has gone almost unchanged. Now let's wait for the first td element with lsm2 class to load, with setting maximum timeout of 5 seconds:"""

    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "lsm2")))
        print("All necessary tables have been loaded successfully")
    except TimeoutException:
        raise("Timeout error")


    """Then we proceed in case of success:"""

    a_ = rnds.find_elements_by_xpath(".//td[@class='lsm2']")
    knt = 0
    for _ in a_:
        knt = knt+1

    print(knt)

    driver.implicitly_wait(2)  # Not sure if it is needed here anymore
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()  # I would also recommend to make sure you quit the driver not only close it if you don't want to kill numerous RAM-greedy Chrome processes by hand 
    return None
```

You can make some experiments and tweak timeout length you need to achieve the necessary result. I would also suggest to use *len(a_)* instead of iterating with *for* loop, but it's up to you.