# Sometimes the element is not found

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have an unordered list after a button click and I want to get the number of how many `ul`s are with `paginated` class.

```
 <ul class="paginated">  </ul>
```

Here is my code:

```
 element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('paginated')
 print(len(element))
```

Sometimes I get 0 but there is one `ul` with `class = paginated`. I used `time.sleep(1)` and it's working perfectly. But I want to make it more dynamical.
Can someone help me with a `WebDriverWait` line code to replace that `time.sleep`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wait until page is loaded with Selenium WebDriver for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/wait-until-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-webdriver-for-python)

Comment: I am checking right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `element_to_be_clickable`()

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul.paginated'))).click()
```

Import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

**Edit**:

```
print(len(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul.paginated')))))
```

Comment: It is not clickable. I need to wait until the element is found on the page

Comment: `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul.paginated')))` I am checking right now with this code line

Comment: @PaulVio : Check the edited answer.If that helps.