# Selenium for crawling javascript in python : using page_source

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

Try to Crawling website's data but these are edited by javascript. So, quit to use beautifulSoup and changed to Selenium.
But, the result is same as follow my code.
As I know, using Selenium, can crawling javascripts htmls, but I couldn't find out these...

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver

for url in Url_Number:
driver = webdriver.Chrome(C:\Python_Study\chromedriver.exe.')
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
Real_url = 'http://www.sbiz.or.kr/sijangtong/nation/onnuri/pop/onnuriShopListPopup.do?cpage=1&mkt_cd=100101&mkt_gubun=O&shop_table=SJTT.MKT_ELE_SHOP'
driver.get(Real_url)
html=driver.page_source 
print(html)
```

> the result of print(html), couldn't figure out table's data which are written as javascript...

How could I approach javascript data by using selenium??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wait until page is loaded with Selenium WebDriver for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/wait-until-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-webdriver-for-python)

Comment: Sadly No, it's slightly different what I want. The thing what I need is 'How to crawling all HTML(the whole text, when I press F12 on page)'.