# How to identify the first element in table using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table//tbody//tr//a[@data-refid='recordId'][0]")))
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
line_item = driver.find_elements("xpath", "//table//tbody//tr//a[@data-refid='recordId'][0]")
print(line_item)
```

I need to find the first element in table which is arr[0] but i am finding no element exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the find_element_by_xpath method and specify the xpath expression for the first element in the table.

Comment: I need to wait for the element to be present wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table//tbody//tr//a[@data-refid='recordId'][0]"))). This particular code [0] is not working

Comment: In xpath how to add "//table//tbody//tr//a[@data-refid='recordId'][0]"  [0] to expression

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out before you can use

```
driver.find_element()
```

It returns the first found element within DOM tree which fits the xpath.

```
driver.find_elements()
```

returns all elements with specified xpath within DOM tree.

using find_element:

```
  wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table//tbody//tr//a[@data-refid='recordId']")))
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    line_item = driver.find_element("xpath", "//table//tbody//tr//a[@data-refid='recordId']")
    print(line_item)
```

using find_elements():

```
 wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table//tbody//tr//a[@data-refid='recordId']")))
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    list_of_all_elements = driver.find_elements("xpath", "//table//tbody//tr//a[@data-refid='recordId']")
    line_item = list_of_all_elements[0]
    print(line_item)
```

This cheatsheet has a good section for locating list/table elements.
[devhints.io/xpath](https://devhints.io/xpath)

Answer (score 0):

To identify the first element in a `<table>` using an index instead of [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Line of code:

  ```
  line_item = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table//tbody//tr//a[@data-refid='recordId']")))[0]
  print(line_item[0])
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to get item url after finding with css selector using selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63125105/7429447)