# How to monitor web's element is changed or not?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I want to buy discounted stuff online,and the websites will let users buy it at certain time with limited amount , so I use selenium to write an automatic program.
and here's  a part of  my code

```
while 1:
    start = time.clock()
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_class_name('SasCheckoutButton__mod___1BK9F.CheckoutBar__buyNowBtn___qgDtR.CheckoutBar__checkoutButton___jSkkJ').click()
        print ('located')
        end=time.clock()
        break
    except:
        print("not yet!")
```

My first idea is to use while to monitor if the button shows up yet ,so that if the button is updated by the website's manager I can press it as soon as possible . but here's the problem , if the web is updated,I don't think I can press it without refreshing , right?(I actually don't know how the engineer manage the web pages , I just guessing based on my experience)  so I have to add refreshing in the while , but I think this will slow down the program a lot , so I am wondering if there's any way in selenium to monitor the changing without refreshing? or maybe a more efficient way to add refreshing in the while? because I don't think refreshing every time it can't find the buy button is a good idea.

Comment: Does this solves your problem ? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/wait-until-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-webdriver-for-python#answer-26567563

Comment: I actually don't have the method to test if WebDriverWait() function is useful or not ,but I wonder that whether it needs refreshing to monitor the changing set by the engineer  or not , if it does not , then I think it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do to monitor how the whole thing works would something like this :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

browser = ...
url = "..."
delay = 3 # seconds
classname = 'SasCheckoutButton__mod___1BK9F.CheckoutBar__buyNowBtn___qgDtR.CheckoutBar__checkoutButton___jSkkJ'

counter = 0
while True:
    counter += 1
    try:
        browser.get(url)
        if counter >= 10:
            break
        myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, classname)))
        print ('located')
        break
    except TimeoutException:
        print(f"reload #{counter}")

myElem.click()
```

Then you could check if you really need to refresh the webpage or if the page "self refreshes" (using something like scripts for example).