# How to use seleinum to click something? javascript:void(0) python

Tags: python

I tried so many ways to click something on a website but it couldn't work.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="ui-btn">一次付清</a>
```

I tried to use xpath to locate the element but it didn't work

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/dl[1]/dd/ul/li[1]/a").click()
```

Comment: Hello! Could you please provide your source code, Thanks!

Comment: Hello! I just updated the question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: May I ask the `a` tag really doesn't have a `href` attribute? cause if it has and you are trying to go to that site, you can simply just get the value of `href` and do a `driver.get(url)`. If that's not the cause I suggest this [Selenium Driver Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/wait-until-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-webdriver-for-python)

Comment: I dont think there is a tag. I have tried driver wait method but I cant locate the element.

Comment: Could you also put the `error` message if any & possible the at least the sample `html` code cause what I think is two things 1.) What the error message says 2.) Probably you might have to review your `xpath`.

Comment: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/dl[1]/dd/ul/li[1]/a"}
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)

Comment: Xpath is evil try ```CSS selectors``` or ```class selectors```. like ```driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".ui-btn")``` or ```driver.find_element_by_class_name("ui-btn")```

Comment: There are multiples un-btn on the html. I am thinking how to add the chinese characters in CSS selectors. Thanks