# Selenium - Issue Getting/Clicking Button Element

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have been messing around with python and selenium and was trying to make a program that could automatically checkout on bestbuy.ca . I have gotten to nearly the last stage of the checkout process but am having difficulty getting the element/clicking the buttons to continue. The only button I have been able to get to work is the add to cart button on the product page.

Here is the site as well as the HTML:

[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYb5R.png)

Some things I have tried with no success include:

`driver.find_element_by_class_name().click()`

- For this, I used the class in button and span. I have tried using each individual class in  separately and together with little success. It would usually give me a "No Element Found" error or just not click anything afterwards.

`driver.driver.find_element_by_xpath().click()`

- For this, I tried using the element locator extension for the xpath as well as "//*[@type='submit']" with no success.

`driver.driver.find_element_by_css_selector().click()`

- For this, I tried the element locator extension again as well as copying it from the firefox inspect with no success.

Not really sure if there are any other ways to go about doing this but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello! A popular one to solve this issue is using the `Wait` in python selenium. You can check it out here and apply it to your code :) 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/wait-until-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-webdriver-for-python)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to copy the entire class attribute from the html and use :

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='asd asd sad asd']"))).click()
```

copy the class and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

Try either of the following to click on the button tag.

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Continue']/parent::button"))).click()
```

Or by attribute data automation

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-automation='review-order']"))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```