# How to replace web-request with html file python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to replace web-request with html file. Link to the file html code https://pastebin.com/BJbgXtg0

**My code**

```
from selenium import webdriver

file_path = "Mark.html"
with open(file_path) as html_file:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    html_content = html_file.read()
    print(html_content) # prints full file -- OK
    print("--------------------")
    driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8,{}".format(html_content))
    print(driver.page_source) # prints only part of the file --- PROBLEM
    print("---------------------------")
    edu_raw = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='education']/div/div/div")
    print(edu_raw)
```

Problem is that `print(driver.page_source)` prints only part of the file

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>Mark Zuckerberg</title><meta name="referrer" content="origin-when-crossorigin" id="meta_referrer"><style type="text/css" nonce="92Mfjw08">/*<![CDATA[*/.bi .bk .cd{color:</style></head><body></body></html>
```

How can print whole file?

Comment: maybe the page you expect is not loaded directly. if it's the case, try to use WebDriverWait. you can read this answer to know how to use it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26567563/13123142 . use it with a selector that you are sure that it will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the file using:

```
driver.get("file://" + absolutePath)
```

Then you may retrieve the content using

```
driver.page_source
```

Another way is to replace the content directly using JS:

```
driver.execute_script(f"var ele=arguments[0]; ele.innerHTML = '{html_content}';", driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html'))
```