# Scrape Product Image with BeautifulSoup (Error)

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, telepot

I need your help. I'm working on a telegram bot which sends me all the sales from amazon.
It works well but this function doesn't work properly. I have always the same error that, however, blocks the script

***imgs_str = img_div.img.get('data-a-dynamic-image')  # a string in Json format
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'img'***

```
 def take_image(soup):
    
    img_div = soup.find(id="imgTagWrapperId")

    imgs_str = img_div.img.get('data-a-dynamic-image')  # a string in Json format

    # convert to a dictionary
    imgs_dict = json.loads(imgs_str)
    #each key in the dictionary is a link of an image, and the value shows the size (print all the dictionay to inspect)
    num_element = 0 
    first_link = list(imgs_dict.keys())[num_element]
    return first_link
```

I still don't understand how to solve this issue.
Thanks for All!

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of the error, `soup.find` didn't work.
Have you tried using `images = soup.findAll("img",{"id":"imgTagWrapperId"})`
This will return a list

Answer (score 0):

Images are not inserted in HTML Page they are linked to it so you need wait until uploaded. Here i will give you two options;

1-) (not recommend cause there may be a margin of error) simply; you can wait until the image is loaded(for this you can use "time.sleep()"

2-)(recommend) I would rather use [Selenium Web Driver](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). You also have to wait when you use selenium, but the good thing is that selenium has a unique function for this job.
I will show how make it with selenium;

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("url")
delay = 3 # seconds
try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'imgTagWrapperId')))# I used what do you want find
    print ("Page is ready!")
except TimeoutException:
    print ("Loading took too much time!")
```

**More Documention**

**[Code example for way 1](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5290126/Nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-findall-while-usi)**

**[Q/A for way 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/wait-until-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-webdriver-for-python)**

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, but i have a question for you. Does it work for all the targets? Prices, Titles, Photos, Discounts etc? or only for photos?

Comment: @Giuseppe, You can use selenium module what do you want to find out. Selenium is useful for many purposes on the internet and it is also effective in finding files loaded with the java script you mentioned above, you just have to know/learn how to use it. I left a link to the documents above, please take a look for more. Good Luck :)

Comment: trying your sketch, myElem doesn't work, so i only print the location i think, not the text. What i should do now?