# Check whether selenium driver is is busy loading at the moment

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have not come across an answer to answers whether it is possible to check at a specific moment in your Python script if the driver is busy loading or not.
Something like:

```
   print(driver == loading)
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Why do you want to know that  ? I could not understand the use case

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked a lot of times before.
Actually you are asking is it possible to validate the page loading was completed.
You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/wait-until-page-is-loaded-with-selenium-webdriver-for-python) and on many similar questions here.
So, you can check page ready state. But it is not reliable enough.

```
def page_has_loaded(self):
    self.log.info("Checking if {} page is loaded.".format(self.driver.current_url))
    page_state = self.driver.execute_script('return document.readyState;')
    return page_state == 'complete'
```

Comment: What other page states are there? Also, my question is actually slightly different.

Comment: document.readyState can be: loading, interactive or complete.  I see you asked slightly different question, but I'm not sure there are better approaches to get the answer. I will be happy to learn if there are such.

Comment: Your suggestion did not solve my problem. After landing in a specific page and clicking on a specific element, a loading icon appears, indicating the driver is loading and going to another page. However, the document.readyState still appears to be "complete".

Comment: Thank you for the response, it is very interesting. Please let me know if you finally got a solution for this question.