# Selenium: how to wait for the browser to load already saved username/password before pressing the login button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

In python:
When I use a specific profile (so there are already saved username and password), What is the best way to wait for the browser to auto-enter data before continuing?

Comment: Perhaps this answer fro a similar question might be of use to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26567563/21941522. You essentially just use `WebDriverWait` to wait for a specified amount of time until the login form finishes loading.

Comment: yes I could use webdriverwait but the problem is not with the page elements! The page elements are all loaded completely. Using a simple sleep(3) I can solve it, but that's not a good thing

Comment: I don't need to send username or password (they are already saved in the browser) but the browser takes a few seconds to load them. I know how to send username and password (if I don't want to use the pre-saved data) and i'm able to click login button

Comment: if you use a specific profile (ex. google chrome profile) you can save username and password (or others info) directly in the browser. So you don't need to send username/password you can store (update, change etc...) them directly in browser. however, before the data is inserted into the respective textboxes there is a small delay and Selenium presses the login button before the browser fills them in (with a time.sleep(3) this is obviated but that's not a good thing)

Answer (score 0):

When an input in a form is filled in it gains an attribute called `"value"`. We can use this to detect if username and password have been filled in.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from typing import Literal

def getConfiguredDriver()->WebDriver:
    """ returns driver with correct options"""
    pass # configure the browser to your preferences


def attempt_login(driver:WebDriver, url:str, delay:float,
                  login_button_element_args:tuple[str,str],
                  username_element_args:tuple[str,str]=(By.ID,"username"),
                  password_element_args:tuple[str,str]=(By.ID,"password")
                 )->bool:
    """
    :param driver: - the browser that is being used
                   NOTE: must be configured to a specific profile.
    :param url: - the url of the page you want the browser to auto-fill
    :param delay: - the maximum amount of time you want the driver to wait in seconds
    
    :param username_element_args: - these are the args that you would pass into driver.find_element
                                    in order to get the username element.
                                    NOTE: in most cases (By.ID,"username") will suffice
    :param password_element_args: - these are the args that you would pass into driver.find_element
                                    in order to get the password element
                                    NOTE: in most cases (By.ID,"password") will suffice
    :param login_button_element_args: - these are the args that you would pass into driver.find_element
                                        in order to get the login button element
                                        NOTE: this must be determined by analysising the target (url) page

    :return: True if successful in logging in, else False
    """
    FORM_ARGS:tuple[tuple[str,str],tuple[str,str]] = (username_element_args, password_element_args)
    driver.get(url)

    def get_value(element: WebElement):
        """
        Apparently element.get_attribute("value") does not work, thus we need to use a JS script,
        to manually extract hidden attribute "value" from the DOM.
        """
        return driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].value;', element)
    
    def predicate(driver:WebDriver)->WebElement|Literal[False]:
        """
        Determines if the username and password field have been filled.
        If it has been filled returns the login button else returns false
        """
        condition:bool = all(get_value(driver.find_element(*args))!="" for args in FORM_ARGS)
        # condition is True if username and password are filled in else False.

        return driver.find_element(*login_button_element_args) if condition else False

    try:
        login_button:WebElement = WebDriverWait(driver,delay).until(predicate)
        login_button.click()
        return True
    except TimeoutException:
        return False

driver:WebDriver = getConfiguredDriver()
url = "my login page"
if (attempt_login(driver,url,3, (By.CLASS_NAME,"login.btn"))):
    print("success")
else:
    print("failure")
```

Note, "username", "password" and "login button" are just filler ids, refer to the html the page you are trying to log into to get the ids of each respective element. Note, this method will work even if you manually copy past username and password into the login form.

Comment: It doesn't work! get.attribute("value") remains empty unless a send_keys(Keys.arrow_right) is sent before "return condition". Example:
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, IDS[0]).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT)

Comment: Appologies, the code was incorrect due to a failure on my theory knowledge. In JS you can extract the text inside of an input field, `elem` by using `elem.value`. Due to my lack of experience in HTML I though `elem.value` was equivalent to `elem.getattribute("value")`. This is why the predicate would always return false, since input field does not have a DOM attribute called `"value"` rather it has in implicit state called `"value"`.

Comment: nothing has changed, it only works if I add: driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "Myxpath").send_keys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT) To simulate a movement in the Textbox