# Chrome and IE doesn't wait for the page to load before taking screenshot

Tags: c#, google-chrome, visual-studio-2013, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I am automating login page for a bootstrap UI.
I want to take a screenshot each time when Login button gets click in Chrome and IE browser **after loading a full page**. In Firefox its working properly, I can see a next page in the screenshot.

Below is my code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void LoginTestChrome(string userName, string pwd)
{
  OpenBrowserChrome();
  IWebElement username = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Label"));
  username.SendKeys(userName);
  IWebElement password = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Pwd"));
  password.SendKeys(pwd);
  driver.FindElement(By.Id("BtnLogin")).Click();
  SaveScreenshot();
  driver.Quit();
}
```

Can anyone solve my problem please?

Comment: What automation tool you are using?

Comment: I am doing it in Visual studio 2013

Comment: can you post your button click

Comment: [TestMethod]
        public void LoginTestChrome(string userName, string pwd)
        {
            OpenBrowserChrome();

            IWebElement username = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Label"));
            username.SendKeys(userName);

            IWebElement password = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Pwd"));
            password.SendKeys(pwd);

            driver.FindElement(By.Id("BtnLogin")).Click();

            
            SaveScreenshot();

            driver.Quit();
        }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reliably detect page load or time out, Selenium 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729483/reliably-detect-page-load-or-time-out-selenium-2)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write code to ensure that the page is properly loaded. You can verify that a Web Element is present on the new page.

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
```

with this code, you are sure that for every browser, Selenium will wait for the element -> page loaded.

KR,

Nicolas

Comment: I tried putting waits in this but still it doesn't work. And to fine element for explicit wait, I don't have any as I am testing login page. When login fails, It should remain on that page only and take screenshot of validation messages given

Comment: Maybe you can wait for this message to appear ? you wait for this to be visible, and then you take a sreenshot. Did you tried this ?