# Use 'find_element_by_partial_link_text("abc")' .If the "abcd" link still matches in the first place,

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I found a problem when using python selenium: Use 
`'find_element_by_partial_link_text("abc")'` .If the `"abcd"` link still matches in the first place, how can I avoid this problem?

I need to exactly match `'abc'`, only match `'abc'`, not `'abcd'`. How should I write it?

Comment: So the first link with "abcd" does match? I don't understand the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use find\_element\_by\_link\_text() properly to not raise NoSuchElementException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936149/how-to-use-find-element-by-link-text-properly-to-not-raise-nosuchelementexcept)

Answer (score 0):

`find_element_by_partial_link_text` will locate any element with partial match. So the string "abc" will match any string containing this sequence ("qabc", "abckj" and so on).

For exact match use `find_element_by_link_text`, without the `partial`.