# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Unable to interact with href link.

Code trials:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome() 
browser.implicitly_wait(5) 
browser.get(URL) 
webbrowser.open(URL) 
#if Size == 'Large': 
ClickS =browser.find_element_by_id('product-select').click() 
SizeS = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//option[@value='12218866696317']").click() 
#Send to cart 
AddtoCart = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='submit']").click() 
GotoCart = browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Cart").click()
```

Code and Error snapshot:

[image]

HTML:

```
<a href="/cart" class="cart-heading">Cart</a>
```

HTML Snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Please add code itself to your question, not screenshots

Comment: When i copied pasted my code a problem would occur and it woudnt let me post it

Comment: It seems your element is hidden. can you post the HTML code rather than snap

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As a new user, you probably should read the [tour] to familiarize yourself with the site. There was [formatting help available](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) while you entered your question; please read it now and [edit] your post. If your unspecified ("a") problem was that your post seems to consist largely of *code*, well, now it largely consists of *images*, which is not an improvement. That message is to encourage you to describe in words what the problem is and what you tried to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element {"method":"link text","selector":"Cart"}
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to locate the desired element as per the line:

```
GotoCart = browser.find_element_by_link_text("Cart").click()
```

### Solution

You need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Cart"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "section#header a.cart-heading[href='/cart']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//section[@id='header']//a[@class='cart-heading' and @href='/cart']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

**PS**: You can find a detailed discussion in [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

Comment: thank you veery much it now works but i have to ask how you got  "section#header a.cart-heading[href='/cart']" for the css selector along with xpath

Comment: The _CssSelector_ was pretty much evident within the image you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

The error is at the bottom of the stack trace, it can't find the element from the link text that you gave it. It's probably the same problem that this person had where the python was going too fast and the page hadn't fully loaded: [How to use find_element_by_link_text() properly to not raise NoSuchElementException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936149/how-to-use-find-element-by-link-text-properly-to-not-raise-nosuchelementexcept)

So just add `browser.implicitly_wait(10)` right after the line where you set `browser`.